# How would chemosynthesis using ammonia(NH3) work?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, chemistry, biochemistry

On a terrestrial planet with a high amount of ammonia vapor in the atmosphere, would any organism have a strong enough incentive to develop some form of autotrophic chemosynthesis that derives energy from the aforementioned ammonia vapor and if so, then how would this work, chemically speaking?

Comment: An interesting question, though pretty sketchy on details. You run the risk of this being closed due to lack of focus. I'd like to invite you to review the [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea how to write a good question. Basically, you need to address what research you've already done and you really should focus on one particular problem or aspect of the evolution of life on this other world. Right now, question is a little broad.

Comment: researching potential life on Titan might help focus your question as I recently read several items aimed at widely different levels.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on more factors than just the mere presence of those vapors.

[Microorganisms do oxidize ammonia to obtain energy:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemosynthesis)

> Many microorganisms in dark regions of the oceans use chemosynthesis to produce biomass from single carbon molecules. Two categories can be distinguished. In the rare sites at which hydrogen molecules (H<sub>2</sub>) are available, the energy available from the reaction between CO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub> (leading to production of methane, CH<sub>4</sub>) can be large enough to drive the production of biomass. Alternatively, **in most oceanic environments, energy for chemosynthesis derives from reactions in which substances such as hydrogen sulfide or ammonia are oxidized**.

But those microorganisms have evolved to adapt to dark environments where ammonia is readily available. In places where both ammonia **and** sunlight are available, photosynthesis is the dominant process, which leads me to believe that it has the best cost-benefit for the ecosystem in the long run.

In a planet where photosynthesizing organisms have not evolved (perhaps it is a dark place), and where you have a practically unlimited supply of ammonia, chemosynthesis may become the dominant factor. However if the sole source of ammonia are biological processes then ecosystems might run out of it over the eons and life might not be viable for millions or billions of years, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Here's an example: https://www.nature.com/articles/ismej200957/